# Преобразование unorganized pointcloud в organized

Tags: c++

Используется библиотека PCL. Передо мной стоит задача - преобразовать неорганизованное облако точек (все точки хранятся в одномерном массиве) в организованное (все точки хранятся в двумерном массиве). Облако является проекцией на координатную систему камеры, т.е. являет собой плоскость, координата z=1. Также известно, что оригинальное разрешение 640*480, однако в используемом облаке есть области без точек, что и приводит к проблеме, количество точек !=307200.